# How can I run Fastlane's Sigh function now that Apple requires 2FA?

Tags: ios, macos, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, fastlane

Previously we setup a user in developer.apple.com that doesn't have 2FA so that we could use the following in our CI/CD:

```
fastlane sigh download_all \
 --team_id=$(TEAM_ID) \
 --app_identifier=$(BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) \
 --username=$(APPLE_ID) \
 --provisioning_name=$(PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME) \
 --output_path=$(PROFILES_DIR) \
 --download_xcode_profiles \
 --readonly
```

I found suggestions online to use the App Store Connect API and create an API Key but it seems that because our organization is an Enterprise org we don't have the option to create API Keys. Is there another way around this? We don't need to use Fastlane if there is another way to do it.

Comment: There is no solution for Enterprise and Fastlane at present - https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions/18049